# Using jQuery, how do you change the image on hover inside of a div?

Tags: jquery, image

I have the following jQuery code to replace an image when you hover over with the mouse but it doesn't seem to be working.  What is wrong with the code below?

```
$(function() {
$("div.delete img")
    .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "../../images/comment-hover-del.png");
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "../../images/comment-del.png");
});
 });
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="delete" id="26"><img src="../../images/comment-del.png" border="0"></div>
```

Comment: A remark independent of your problem: IDs in HTML may not start with a digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rearrange it a bit, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("div.delete").hover(function() {
     $("img", this).attr("src", "../../images/comment-hover-del.png");
  }, function() {
     $("img", this).attr("src", "../../images/comment-del.png");
  });
});
```

This is triggered on hover of the div, since there might be a slight flash when the image changes, resulting in the image collapsing and the `mouseout` firing before the next image loads.  I'd assign a width/height to the `<div>` if you use the method above to prevent this behavior, or to the image if you use your current method.

Alternatively, you could give the `div` a `background-image` css property and the `<div>` itself a hover (removing the `<img>` completely) and do this all in CSS, like this:

```
div.delete { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-image: url('../../images/comment-del.png') center;
}
div.delete:hover { 
  background-image: url('../../images/comment-hover-del.png') center;
}
```

Comment: -1 for not posting simple/quick solution, also suggesting something in latter part done done asked by OP

Comment: @phpBOY - I posted the *best* solution in this case, the simple solution isn't always a **correct** one.  See the other answer, it doesn't solve the problem at all, which I describe in detail in my answer and how it resolves it.

Comment: @oo - I'd do `.live('mouseenter', func).live('mouseleave', func)` for a better feel in most cases, if you ever have a child of the hovered element, it makes a big difference, just a good convention to stay with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
$("div.delete")
    .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", "../../images/comment-hover-del.png");
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", "../../images/comment-del.png");
});
 });
```

Comment: This is incorrect, his selector is already for an `<img>`, you're looking for `<div><img><img /></img></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my original code was OK but I just realized the image and div were being put there dynamically.  So because of that I needed to use the live event below.

(I realized this after some good answers also didn't work, which made no sense.)

```
$('div.delete img').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        $(this).attr("src", "../../images/comment-del-hover.png");
    } else {
         $(this).attr("src", "../../images/comment-del.png");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do effects like this though. If you want to change src and also be able to animate it go for this:

```
$("#clone_el").css("z-index",2);
ele = $("#clone_el").clone().css({position:"relative","top":"-"+$("#clone_el").eq(0).height()+"px","z-index":"1"}).attr("src","/path/to/new/src");

$("#clone_el").after(ele).fadeOut();
```